# If you can send emails from server, but cannot configure desktop client, can you say SMTP is working?

Tags: 12.04, server, email, postfix, smtp

This question is a somewhat prologue to a different question posted ([here)](https://serverfault.com/questions/565332/vps-smtp-working-on-server-client-roundcube-but-cannot-be-configured-on-deskt). As I can state that I can send email from my Ubuntu server (12.04) via Roundcube, perfectly. However, I cannot manage to correctly configure my desktop email client on my Mac. And I feel the problem lies in the SMTP port.

However, I want to know where I should be debugging. Therefore I want to know: If I can send emails from the server, via Roundcube, can I state that the SMTP server/postfix is correctly installed/configured/working?

Edit: Just found this information, which made help:

> Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-01-06 15:50 CET
>
> Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
>
> Host is up (0.0000060s latency).
>
> Not shown: 993 closed ports
>
> PORT     STATE SERVICE
>
> 21/tcp   open  ftp
>
> 22/tcp   open  ssh
>
> 53/tcp   open  domain
>
> 80/tcp   open  http
>
> 110/tcp  open  pop3
>
> 143/tcp  open  imap
>
> 3306/tcp open  mysql

`sudo netstat -tlnp
root@vps:~# sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2550/master

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      779/mysqld

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      758/dovecot

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      758/dovecot

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1002/apache2

tcp        0      0 159.253.1.196:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      744/named

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      744/named

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      665/sshd

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2550/master

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      744/named

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      758/dovecot

tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      946/proftpd: (accep
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      665/sshd

tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      2550/master`

Comment: None of the typical SMTP ports (25, 587, 465) seem to be open and listening, so the host you scanned does not provide any kind of SMTP service on localhost interface. If the service is not available on external interface(s), I would say that the SMTP server is **not** properly configured.

Comment: can you add the output of `sudo netstat -tlnp`

Comment: I guess you're looking for this
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2550/master     
` or `tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      2550/master   ` complete list posted in main post

Comment: What error(s) were reported by the MUA clients when trying to configure them to use your server? It appears that SMTP is listening to port 25 on IPv4 and IPv6. Most likely problem is Postfix configuration for SMPTauth.

Comment: While configuring Airmail, it said 'A stable connection to the server could not be established.', while I could configure it in Apple Mail (which does not check the configuration, apparently), it says "The server mail.MYDOMAIN.nl has a connection via the default gateways rejected (Default gateways = 25,467, 587 )

Comment: As I can't find the 'edit' button on my comment, as I can on other StackExchanges, let me add this: On both error messages, it also says 'SMTP tests failed' - so the problem should be the SMTP configuration, I guess? - Edit: Strange, I can edit this comment, but my Previous comment, I can't.

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer  Run a pass of your domain through [MXToolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com) particularly the SMTP tests. This might shed some clues as to how your SMTP connections are responding. Presuming that your are running Postfix, there are a lot of variables that can affect SMTP auth working properly.

Comment: As copy-pasting the text is too much, please check out these screenshots from the MXToolbox. -> http://nl.tinypic.com/r/344pmqp/5 - Btw, I'm running multiple websites on a single VPS, all with there DNS set to my VPS IP and all mail/smtp DNS records are dynamic, which are mail.domainname.nl - So all 8 domains on my VPS all have different mail DNS records. Does that matter, or should I configure them to all use one single mail record, such as the mail records from my main domain? Thanks! - Oh and I do use Postfix. Configured with only my main domain

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer Good - SMTP connections are coming in, your results look normal for a dynamic-IP server. Next up would be to see your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file for how your auth settings are configured. I've [posted mine](http://pastebin.com/N1Vm1v9T) for you to check as a comparison - it's probably going to be in the `smtpd_` settings that you need a tweak.

Comment: Checked yours, added 1 or 2 lines, but errors remain the same. Check out my config: http://pastebin.com/5zQz1AJx - However, I was wondering. Could it perhaps by the server address? The DNS settings of the domain have a A record which is mail.<domain>.nl and a value that points to my VPS (IP) - I'm using that in my configuration in my mail client. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer Your DNS looks good and MXToolbox had no issues getting an SMTP connection - just your clients are having trouble getting a good connection which is probably because most want to use TLS. Based on what I'm seeing in your `main.cf` entries, it looks like you have conflicting settings for using TLS; comment out the remaining lines in your section `# tls config` and add `permit_inet_interfaces , permit_tls_clientcerts` to your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions=` line. There may still be a few more edit to make but lets start there and see what happens.

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer Also, before making major edits to your `main.cf` file, you may want to make a backup of it using `sudo cp /etc/postfix/main.cf /etc/postfix/main.cf.backup`

Comment: Still same problem: Cannot create a stable connection with the server; Annoying It does not say an error code or where the obstruct is.. Anyway, I can't connect myself either, on any mail client on my Mac desktop. Strange that the server client (round cube) does works.. By the way; whether I use none, start TLS or SSL as a security for the SMTP server, each option gives same result - For as far as that matters. Thanks in advance mate - If you can fix this, I will surely buy you a beer!

Comment: Ok crap, just tested and the server side client (round cube) doesn't work either, anymore.. Which did work before creating this thread.. However, it does gives a good error, which can help.. probably. It says 'SMTP Error (-1): Cannot connect with the server' - Does that rings any bells? Thanks in advance! - P.s. error keeps in place, even when copying the backup back to /etc/postfix/main.cf ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12354/discussion-between-douggro-and-sander-schaeffer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I'm so glad this issue has been fixed! After a lot of googling, I found the solution myself. However, many steps need to have been taken!

`postfix` should be configured well. Gladly I had a second VPS with correct postfix configuration (which I completely forgot) - This one doesn't have a correct configuration either, though. Time to fix that.

Apparantly, after a lot of `sudo mmap <server ip>` and using `telnet <port number>` plus googling to `port 25`, I found out that `port 25` is blocked by my ISP. Or.. I think so.

Therefor, I went into the Postfix master file (`sudo nano /etc/postfix/master.cf`) and pasted this line `submission inet n      -       n       -       -       smtpd` within the file. This opens Postfix on port 587 and will have Postfix use port 587 instead of port 25.

After that, just enable `port 587` in your server firewall (`sudo ufw allow 587`) and after checking with my desktop mail client, I can verify: It's working!

If anyone has an issue like this, just open chat / comment or something. I'd like to help. However: My skills are equal to your grandmother's skills with computers, so don't expect much: Though, I managed to fix this... =)